# Is there a way to use impersonation on a specific folder (e.g., calendar) instead of the whole user mailbox?

Tags: exchange, microsoft-office-365, exchangeonline

Is there a way to use Impersonation on a specific folder (e.g., calendar) instead of the whole user mailbox ?

I know we can create and narrow down a ManagementScope such as:

```
New-ManagementScope -Name "My Scope" -RecipientRestrictionFilter {RecipientTypeDetails -eq "RoomMailbox"}
```

then assign this management scope to a user having ApplicationImpersonation role, but I was wondering if there is a command that allows to do the same on UserMailbox, but only on the calendar folder (or any other specifically mentioned) ?

Something like `{RecipientTypeDetails -eq "UserMailbox" -folder "xxx:\Calendar"}` ?

I could do this restriction using delegation as in:

```
Get-Mailbox -RecipientTypeDetails UserMailbox | Foreach-Object {Add-MailboxFolderPermission $_”:\Calendar” -User xxxxx -AccessRights Editor}
```

But can we do something similar with Impersonation ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on my research, it seems that there are no parameters which are used to specify the folder scope in the [**New-ManagementScope**](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/exchange/role-based-access-control/new-managementscope?view=exchange-ps#syntax) command and the **[recipient properties](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/exchange/exchange-server/recipient-filters/recipientfilter-properties?view=exchange-ps)**(**-RecipientRestrictionFilter**).